# Please run this code and tell me why got this result

Tags: c, for-loop, char, bit-shift, bitwise-and

why the result of " (num >> i)& 1 " is 1 for the second loop?

```
main() {
  char num = 5 ; 
  int i , count = 0 ;

  for(i=0;i<8;i++){
    if ((num >> i)& 1 )
        count++;    
  }
  printf("%d", count);
}
```

Comment: Simple answer; it isn't. It is `1` only in the first and third iterations, but running the code does not show that. You have to move the `printf` inside the loop (and add a newline). The `2` that is ouput does not been the secoind loop: it means that there were two bits that were set to `1`.

Comment: Sorry typos I can't correct now: The `2` that is output does not mean the second loop: it means that there were two bits of `num` that were set to `1`. The decimal value `5` in binary is `00000101`.

Comment: So why can't you run this code yourself?

Answer (score 1):

For starters pay attention to that the variable num itself is not being changed within the for loop

```
  for(i=0;i<8;i++){
    if ((num >> i)& 1 )
        count++;    
  }
```

Its binary representation is

```
00000101
```

(Note take into account that the declaration

```
char num = 5 ;
```

differs from the declaration

```
char num = '5' ;
```

- end note.)

In the first iteration of the loop when i is equal to 0 the shift operator has no effect so the if statement evaluates to logical true and the variable count will be incremented.

The variable count also will be incremented when i is equal to 2.

So as a result you will get that count is equal to 2 because in the internal representation of the variable num only two bits are set..

To make it more clearer rewrite the program the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char num = 5 ; 
    int count = 0 ;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
    {
        int result = (num >> i)& 1;
        printf( "i = %d, result = %d\n", i, result );
        if ( result ) count++;    
    }
    
    printf( "\ncount = %d\n", count );
}
```

The program output is

```
i = 0, result = 1
i = 1, result = 0
i = 2, result = 1
i = 3, result = 0
i = 4, result = 0
i = 5, result = 0
i = 6, result = 0
i = 7, result = 0

count = 2
```

In fact the output from top to bottom shows the internal representation of the variable num starting from its less significant bit to the most significant bit.